# How to express chainging BLE rssi in android BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I'm trying to show chainging rssi on the list that shows scanned device.

[enter image description here][1]

I want to express chainging rssi value at rssi : _____ from the picture.
I'm able to get chainging rssi value on log, like the picture.

[enter image description here][2]

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Comment: Also, your images are missing

Answer (score 0):

You will need a scan intervall, that "refreshes" the RSSI by rescanning for devices. Sth. like this:

```
public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable)
{
    final static int SCAN_PERIOD = 2000; //2s
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    //to start or stop scanning (true/false)
    if (enable)
    {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                if (mGatt == null)
                    offScan();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    }
    else
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```